# Want to return response from middleware after every view call in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Hi I have created middleware for checking user authentication

User Authentication is been checked on another server, therefore, I have to call every time a request comes on view call

```py
class CheckUserMiddleware:
    """Check User logged-in"""

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        """code to be executed every time view is called"""

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
   

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        """ checks weather user is valid or not """
        token_info  = request.headers['Authorization']
        # request._result = get_user(token_info, url)
        result      = get_user(token_info, url)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            return None
        else:
            status_code = status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
            message = "Token is invalid or expired"
            token_type = "access"
            detail = "Given token not valid for any token type"
            result = {
                'message'   : message,
                'token_type': token_type,
                'detail'    : detail,
                'status'    : status_code,
            }
            result = json.dumps(result)
            return HttpResponse(content=result, content_type='application/json')

    def process_template_response(self, request, response):
        """return template response"""

        token_info    = request.headers['Authorization']
        result        = get_user(token_info, url)
        status_code   = status.HTTP_200_OK
        json_response = result.json()
        email         = json_response['email']
        user_id       = json_response['user_id']
        user_type     = json_response['user_profile'][0]['user_type']
        middle = {
            'eamil'         : email,
            'user_id'       : user_id,
            'user_type'     : user_type,
        }

        return HttpResponse(content=middle, content_type='application/json')
```

Now after every call, I need to return user_id in the response

I have created `middle JSON` and am trying to return along with every view call.

but the error that I see when I try to return middle JSON

```
(pdb) AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'render'
```

or this on the terminal.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Can anyone please guide me on how should I proceed.

Please `Note: Process View is working fine, I find issue persists in process_template_response`

Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this out,

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.response import Response

def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    response = Response(
        data={}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
    )
    response.accepted_renderer = JSONRenderer()
    response.accepted_media_type = "application/json"
    response.renderer_context = {}
    return response
```

Comment: The issue is in ```process_template_response``` but I will surely give a try in there too

Comment: It has resolved the errors, but it has removed the data which incoming from view class rather than in appending that?

Comment: I mean now the only JSON is response is getting there in output, not the incoming views data?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're forgetting to turn middle response into json, with `middle = json.dumps(middle)` before returning the HttpResponse

Comment: Still the same ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: ordinal not in range(128)```

Comment: or ``This AttributeError: 'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'render'
> /home/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py(143)_get_response()
-> response = response.render()```